# Is there a way to get the socket reference by using CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tcp

I am creating a socket tcp connection using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost` like this to get a write stream (I dont want to ready any data):

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)host, port, NULL, &writeStream);
```

This works pretty well but because of the [nagle's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) my tcp commands are buffered. This may be cool but in my case I need to send the command as fast as possible without any delays.

I found a way to disable this "feature" using the following code found [here](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/290086-flushing-nsoutputstream-gotten-from-nsnetservice.html):

```
int yes = 1;
setsockopt(CFSocketGetNative(aSocket), IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (void *)&yes, sizeof(yes));
```

but I cant figure out how to get a valid reference to my socket. Can you help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
CFDataRef socketData = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
CFSocketNativeHandle handle;
CFDataGetBytes(socketData, CFRangeMake(0, sizeof(CFSocketNativeHandle)), &handle);
// handle now contains the same thing as CFSocketGetNative(aSocket)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, helped me a lot (14 months ago... :-))