# Call to get native socket for CFStream always fails on iOS

Tags: ios, core-foundation

I use the following code to get the native socket handle in an iOS app.

```
CFReadStreamRef readStream = NULL;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)@"example.com", 443, &readStream, &writeStream);

Boolean readOpen = CFReadStreamOpen(readStream);
Boolean writeOpen = CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream);

CFDataRef socketData = CFWriteStreamCopyProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle);
if (socketData == NULL) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get native socket!"); // Always fails
}
```

However, the result of the function `CFWriteStreamCopyProperty` is always `NULL`. Both calls to open the socket are successful (`readOpen` and `writeOpen` are true). I could not find any documentation on why this might fail. What could the reason be that this code is not working as expected?

Comment: the api you called is wrong:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082686/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-socket-reference-by-using-cfstreamcreatepairwithsocket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stream might be opened in the background in which case `CFWriteStreamOpen` will always return true and the status of the stream will be `kCFStreamStatusOpening`. Only after the stream was successfully opened can you get the native socket. You can use `CFWriteStreamScheduleWithRunLoop` to listen for the open complete event.